# Bring Background image above a div

Tags: html, css

I have a class that has a loading image as a background image:

```
.loader {
  background-image: url('loader.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: center;
}
```

Now, this class is used in a div that also contains the rest of my HTML element:

eg

```
<div class="lodaer"> 
...
 code for a form with many inputs or any other random code
...
</div>
```

Now, when this class is applied, the image comes below the input boxes and other elements. However, my intention is to show the user a loader on top of the form with the form having a lower opacity, indicating the form data is being fetched.

So, how can I get the image on top the other elements? TIA

Comment: Put it on a separate div with a higher z-index that appears on top of it to act as an overlay instead of on the container itself.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like this? <div class="loader></div><div>... my form...</div>. If yes, then the loader class won't know the height and width of the code that it encapsulates and therefore won't be able to properly overlay on the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just something like this; Except in your case replace the css :after with your image on on the loader div as background how you had it.

```css
@keyframes spin { to { transform: rotate(360deg); }}

section {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: gray 3px solid;
}

.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  border: red 1px solid;
}

.loader:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border: silver 5px solid;
  border-top: red 5px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <section>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <div class="loader"></div>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <div class="loader"></div>
  </section>

</main>
```

Comment: What role does position relative property play? It seems quite an important one.

Comment: @RohanAgarwal In this case it's acting as the relative container for the absolute children. So it creates the boundary the absolute children elements refer to within the element instead of the DOM that it would by default be position static. You can learn more [in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) found around the web. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to place the `background-image` above the content. Perhaps the ["before"](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) or ["after"](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp) selector can help you in that case.

I personally would use another div with the loading image above the content, with `position: absolute`. Like this:

```css
.loader-img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 30%;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Big_%26_Small_Pumkins.JPG/1024px-Big_%26_Small_Pumkins.JPG);
}
```

```html
<div class="yourDiv"> 
  ...
   code for a form with many inputs or any other random code
  ...

  <div class="loader-img"></div>
</div>
```